# How to handle both click and double click in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I want to create paint application with silverligh, but I have the problem. I have a color rectangle When click the rectangle the shape will be stroked and double click to fill the shape. My code below not work exactly, when double click the  first `ClickCount` is 1 and then increasing to 2. Can you tell me how to fix it. Thanks.

```
    private void Rect0_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ClickCount == 2)
        {
            RectFront1.Fill = Rect0.Fill;
        }
        else
        {
            RectFront.Fill = Rect0.Fill;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this post (http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dbd951/how-to-handle-double-click-in-silverlight-5/) the e.ClickCount has the following behavior.

The count is calculated based on the time between first click and the second click.
Quote from the post.

> Consider if you are trying to click 5 times. After 3rd click, if you
>   give 200 milliseconds gab between the 3rd and 4th click then the 4th
>   click will be treated as the 1st click. It will reset the ClickCount
>   property if the time between the first click and second click is
>   greater the 200 milliseconds.

Alternativly you could think about having a behavior for a double click since I assume that you would use it quite often in a paint application. 
Here is a good article: 
Double-Click event in silverlight on framework element.
http://blog.cylewitruk.com/2010/10/double-click-event-in-silverlight-on-frameworkelement/

The third option I can think of would be using RX (https://www.nuget.org/stats/packages/Rx-Silverlight) 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh242985.aspx

```
Observable.FromEvent<MouseButtonEventArgs>(myControl, "MouseLeftButtonDown").TimeInterval().Subscribe(evt =>
    {
        if (evt.Interval.TotalMilliseconds <= 300)
        {
            // Do something on double click
        }
    });
```

which was a answer on this question: [Cleanest single click + double click handling in Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274378/cleanest-single-click-double-click-handling-in-silverlight)